# How to display the name of the day of the week from Date() in swift

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I am working on a project in swift where I call the international formatted date from Date() and put it into a text label. I got it to work, but I need it to also say the name of the day of the week in front of it, for example:

Thursday, 11-May-2017

and I don't know the dd-MMM-yyyy format to do that, if there is one. I have searched for it but I have not found anything. I am new to swift and would greatly appreciate some assistance.

So far, my code looks like this. In the view controller I have an outlet to the label just under the view controller class.

```
         @IBOutlet weak var dateDisplay: UILabel!
```

Then in the override viewDidLoad() function, I have my the code that formats the system date to the international form

```
let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    let result = formatter.string(from: date)
    dateDisplay.text! = result
    todayDate = result
```

Then outside of the view controller class but still in the view controller I have a variable

```
 var todayDate: String = ("")
```

Right now it puts "11-May-2017" into the label. 
I want to put "Thursday-11-May-2017" into the label. Is there any way to do that?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this format to format it in the way you want,

```
let date = Date()
let format = "EEEE-dd-MMM-yyyy"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = format

dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it would be that simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do not use `YYYY`. Use `yyyy`. They are different and no one ever actually wants `YYYY`.

Comment: @rmaddy How are they different ? Just curious

Comment: See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns